# Read words from keyboard into a C 2D array

Tags: c

I would need some help after googling like 2 hours with no luck. (Maybe i'm just formulating my question incorrectly?)

I need to read 10 words from keyboard, and show a warning if any of the last 9 words are bigger than the first word.

I know how to use strlen to determine the last part of the request, but I have no idea how to do the first one.

My code looks like this:

```
const int ARRAY_SIZE = 10;
const int MAX_WORD_SIZE = 101;

int main() {
    char arr[ARRAY_SIZE][MAX_WORD_SIZE];

    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < MAX_WORD_SIZE; ++j) {
            printf("Add word %d:\n", i+1);
            scanf("%s", arr[i][j]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But it does not work. cLion tell me "Format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'int'".
I really don't understand why this doesn't work.

Comment: `scanf("%s", arr[i][j]);` -> `scanf("%s", arr[i]);` and remove the inner loop as you are reading an entire string not individual characters.

Comment: also limit the number of characters *scanf* reads to not write of the the receiving array, so `scanf("%100s", arr[i])` (one less to have place for the final null character)

Comment: @kaylum  perhaps `scanf("%100[^\n]",...` would be better

Comment: @EdHeal Yep agreed.

Comment: Or even `scanf(" %100[^\n]"` witha space to filter the previous newline.

Comment: @kaylum, bruno and Ed,  thanks a lot for the reply, I think I understand what is happening. However, I don't understand what the deal with [^\n]. Can you explain that a bit please?

Comment: `%s` stops scanning at the first whitespace, howver is *does* filter the previous whitespace left in the buffer, unlike `%[]`.

Comment: @WeatherVane - Good point

Comment: @DavidBotezatu - `[]` bit is set of - `^` is not `\n` is new line. All together it is a set of characters that are not new line. The `%100` bit is the maximum length of the string. You need an array for an extra character to hold end of line character i.e. 0, I hope this helps

Comment: @EdHeal oh yes it does! 1 think that is still not clear for me though: the normal format is ```"%s"```. However, you removed the "s" in ```scanf(" %100[^\n]")```. Why? I mean, for example when you format a float you have ```%.2f```, so following the same pattern you should have ```scanf(" %100s[^\n]")``` or ```scanf(" %100[^\n]s")```.

Comment: @DavidBotezatu - Please read [scanf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf)

Comment: @DavidBotezatu - I misread - you want `words` - i.e. no spaces. So `scanf("%100S"` WOULD BE FINE

Comment: @EdHeal I understand now. Never crossed my mind there are man pages for C keywords...

Comment: @DavidBotezatu - It is not a keyword - but a part of a library of functions. Other libraries exist. e.g. Create windows etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"%s"` expects a memory address to where it is supposed to start saving the string.

You have a two dimensional array `arr[ARRAY_SIZE][MAX_WORD_SIZE];`. When you use `[]` once you get a 1-dimension array, which is what `%s` expects.

But since you are using `[]` twice, you are getting a single element of that array type, which is char.

change your scanf to: `scanf("%s", arr[i]);` to fix that.

Having noticed that, you can get rid of the inner for loop and variable `j`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i) {
            printf("Add word %d:\n", i+1);
            scanf("%s", arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: Please see my comment above - buffer overruns?!

Answer (score 1):

The solution to your problem would be:

```
const int ARRAY_SIZE = 10;
const int MAX_WORD_SIZE = 101;

int main() {
    char arr[ARRAY_SIZE][MAX_WORD_SIZE];

    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i) {
        printf("Add word %d:\n", i+1);
        scanf(" %s", arr[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It is a good practice to put a blank space in " %s". This way, chars such us \n are ommited, and many problems which stem from here are avoided.

If you wanted to do

```
for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < MAX_WORD_SIZE; ++j) {
            printf("Add word %d:\n", i+1);
            scanf("%s", arr[i][j]);
        }
}
```

you would be reading character by character, so you would have to do instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < MAX_WORD_SIZE; ++j) {
            printf("Add word %d:\n", i+1);
            scanf("%c", arr[i][j]);
        }
}
```

This way of solving the problem may give rise to another problem: not all words have the maximum size so this would be fixed by:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < MAX_WORD_SIZE; ++j) {
            printf("Add word %d:\n", i+1);
            scanf("%c", arr[i][j]);
            if(arr[i][j]=='\n'){
               break;
            }
        }
}
```

Anyway, the first one is the best solution.

Comment: It's entirely unnecessary to place a space before `%s`, but *is* a generally good idea before `%c`. Some explanation: most of the format specifiers for `scanf` automatically filter leading whitespace, but `%c` and `%[]` and `%n` do not. Adding a space in front of the `%` instructs `scanf` to filter leading whitespace here too.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But both methods actually read character by character right?